# React native video does not use play audio using exoplayer

Tags: react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I'm working on a react native project and i needed to use subtitles so i started using exoplayer with react native video, the problem is that now i don't have audio on any video, does anyone know how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use  `react-native-exoplayer` but this module has a lot of problems,
now I use the `react-native-video` and I find it better than exoplayer and you can try using it from this [link](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video)

and this is an example from `react-native-video`:

```
// Load the module

import Video from 'react-native-video';

// Within your render function, assuming you have a file called
// "background.mp4" in your project. You can include multiple videos
// on a single screen if you like.

<Video source={{uri: "background"}}   // Can be a URL or a local file.
       ref={(ref) => {
         this.player = ref
       }}                                      // Store reference
       onBuffer={this.onBuffer}                // Callback when remote video is buffering
       onError={this.videoError}               // Callback when video cannot be loaded
       style={styles.backgroundVideo}

selectedTextTrack={{                 // Subtitles
  type: "title",
  value: "English Subtitles"
}}

selectedVideoTrack={{
  type: "resolution",
  value: 480
}}

 />

// Later on in your styles..
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundVideo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: how about the ability to display subtitles as OP mentioned?

Comment: selectedTextTrack
Configure which text track (caption or subtitle), if any, is shown.

selectedTextTrack={{
  type: Type,
  value: Value
}}
Example:

selectedTextTrack={{
  type: "title",
  value: "English Subtitles"
}}